# How to use ask-sdk with node js, If I am using my own endpoint?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am going to create my own endpoint means not using aws lambda function.

Can I use ask-sdk with node js for writing code in my endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

This still isn't possible without a small workaround - it's been asked a few times on GitHub.

[This](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues/362#issuecomment-384686134) is a possible solution if you're using `express`:

```
// When deploying to your own server (not Lambda)

const Alexa = require('ask-sdk');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

let skill;


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/', function(req, res) {

  if (!skill) {

    skill = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
      .addRequestHandlers(
        HelloWorldHandler
      )
      .create();

  }

  skill.invoke(req.body)
    .then(function(responseBody) {
      res.json(responseBody);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).send('Error during the request');
    });

});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Development endpoint listening on port 3000!');
});
```

You *could* also consider [`alexa-js`](https://github.com/alexa-js/alexa-app#express) - they support it out of the box and have an example.

Comment: Thanks Che!!! 
I have one doubt, I used Alexa Skill code generator and got a below code
const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.standard();
exports.handler = skillBuilder
    .addRequestHandlers(
        AMAZON_FallbackIntent_Handler,
        OnOffIntent_Handler, 
        SessionEndedHandler
    )
    .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
    .lambda();

here handler is using .lambda function. Is this code will use only in while creating lambda function in AWS?

Comment: Yeah, what you have posted is for lambdas (hence the `.lambda()` part). In my example it basically means you can _set it up_ then _invoke_ it. The reason is that Lambda params are the body, context and callback. You'll notice my example only has the body to invoke. BTW, if you want to deploy it to your own endpoint, just use what's in the development environment part - I'll update my answer.